Use invest() form Investr package for a list of nls() model fits
I have a list with two nls models. I would like to use the function invest() from package Investr to do an inverse estimation. I have used other fuctions like summary(), coef(), etc with lapply and seq_along() to produce outputs for each fit. I tried something similar with invest() but it does not work.
Could I get some help on how to use the Invester function in the list of models?
Many thanks
I tried to use the function in the following way, but I have not succeeded.
lapply(seq_along(model.list), function(i) {
    invest(model.list[[i]],y0=0.5)}
)

I made up some data from other data I found in the forum. Fits might not be the best but I think it should be good enough to work with.
try.data <- structure(list(x = 0:77, y = c(0.991744341,0.512512332,0.411024493,0.356621906,0.320851602,
                                           0.294991985,0.275037747,0.25938851,0.245263624,0.233655094,
                                           0.224041427,0.214152907,0.207475139,0.203270739,0.194942529,
                                           0.188107107,0.180926819,0.17702856,0.172595417,0.166729222,
                                           0.163502461,0.159286528,0.156110098,0.152655499,0.148684858,
                                           0.147336054,0.144691873,0.143118853,0.139542186,0.137730139,
                                           0.134353615,0.1321978,0.128369567,0.124971835,0.120027536,
                                           0.117678812,0.115720611,0.11249133,0.109219168,0.942157124,
                                           0.486886716,0.390473268,0.33879081,0.304809022,0.280242386,
                                           0.26128586,0.246419084,0.233000443,0.221972339,0.212839356,
                                           0.203445262,0.197101382,0.193107202,0.185195402,0.178701752,
                                           0.171880478,0.168177132,0.163965646,0.158392761,0.155327338,
                                           0.151322202,0.148304593,0.145022724,0.141250615,0.139969251,
                                           0.13745728,0.13596291,0.132565077,0.130843632,0.127635935,
                                           0.12558791,0.121951089,0.118723243,0.114026159,0.111794872,
                                           0.109934581,0.106866763,0.10375821),
                                           z=rep(factor(c("exp1","exp2")),each=39)),
                                           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(0:77),
                                           .Names = c("x", "y","z"))
try.data=split(try.data,try.data$z)

model.list=lapply(try.data, function(a) nlsLM(y ~ 1/(b + x^c),
                                   start = list(b=0.2, c=-0.2),
                                   control = list(maxiter=250) ,
                                   data = a))

